# Geometric or analytic proof that in hyperbola, $c^2=a^2+b^2$

Tags: conic-sections

How to prove (geometric or analytic) that in hyperbola $c^2=a^2+b^2$? Given that $a$ is the undirected distance of the center to one of the vertices, $b$ is the undirected distance of one of the endpoints of the conjugate axis and $c$ is the undirected distance from the center to one of the foci.

Comment: This should be tagged as conic-sections, geometry instead of algebraic-geometry.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ simply semi major and minor axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the eccentricity of a hyperbola is defined as $e = \sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$. You know that $c = ae$ (by definition), therefore $c^2 = a^2 e^2 = a^2 (1+ \frac{b^2}{a^2}) = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: How does the eccentricity of a hyperbola is defined as $e=√1+b2/a2$ ?

Comment: That and the linear eccentricity $c$ are defined/explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Features